# Prevent Eclipse CDT rebuilding dependencies when there are no changes

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I have been using Eclipse for the past two years for an embedded linux project.
I am able to run my code on Unbutu host unchanged and as such do most of my testing 
on the host.  Each project has a Debug configuration for host and Target-Debug for
embedded linux device that builds with cross compile toolchain.

My workspace has more than 20 projects which consist of libraries and executables that 
reference the libraries.  The problem I have is that anytime I build an executable there seems to no rhyme or reason to the way eclipse rebuilds the referenced libraries.  It will nearly always build several of them when no changes to any of the code in the libraries has changed.  When it builds the libraries it builds all of the source in them, not just a few files.  In some cases it will do so even when the target executable is up to date and not itself rebuilt.  I can clean the executable, then build.  Right away do another build and instead of reporting everything is up to date it might still build some of the libraries.  Build another time and it might build the same libraries again or in some cases finally report that everything is up to date.

Every build configuration for an executable has the exact library build referenced as opposed to "active".  For example for a Target-Debug executable build configuration I reference the Target-Debug build of the libraries it depends on.  When I build executables it is often possible that the "active" build configuration selected for libraries are not the same as executable I'm building but that shouldn't matter if the build configuration for the executable references specific library build configurations.

At one time the problem included rebuilding configurations that weren't even of the same
type.  That is, building a Debug version of executable would also cause Target-Debug configurations of libraries to be rebuild also.  That problem seem to be resolved by unchecking Project References (as opposed to C/C++ General/Paths and Symbols/References).

I experienced this same problem with Helios, Juno and now Kepler with respective CDT releases.

How can I prevent eclipse from re-building dependent library projects when they haven't changed? I have tried everything to figure out why it's happening and search for solutions.  Maybe some misunderstanding on my part of some concept in eclipse build?  I'm at a loss...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.